# Firebase UI 2.0.1 is not working when initializing or calling FirebaseAuth.getInstance() in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to solve the error below, since I updated to Firebase ui 2.0.1. I have set up the project really well since I have worked with previous versions Firebase for a long time.

The error appears when `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` is called.

```
Error:(29, 22) error: cannot access zu class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zu not found
```

Comment: please consider posting your code

Comment: seems like duplicated dependencies. check you gradle or modules probably they are including multiple same dependencies multiple times

Comment: Firebase UI has nested dependencies. Their version is also important in terms of compatibility. Have you made sure that you have the correct nested dependencies installed?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase UI 2.0.1 is using Play services version 11.0.1. Make sure you don't use other versions (like in my case 11.0.2)

Comment: perfact answer. I love you.